# Check with regex if a filename string contains a given substring

Tags: c#, regex

So, I am trying to write a method that checks if a filename contains the name of its owner in order to display it elsewhere.

The string corresponding to the filename always changes (so does the owner), but it follows a pattern of ***prefix(es) - owner - suffix(es) .pdf|xlsx*** .

For example:  **Workflow - Personalized - MY INDUSTRY LTDA - Shared participation.xlsx**

What I have built until now is:

```
public static bool FileBelongsToOwner(string filename, string owner)
        {
            owner = owner.Replace("/", "_");            
            string pattern = string.Format(@"{0}(\s-\s.+)\.(pdf|xlsx)", owner);

            return Regex.IsMatch(filename, pattern);
        }
```

It seems there is something wrong with my regex code because it returns false even when the owner is indeed correct. What would be the ideal regex for this?

Comment: what is logic behind finding out `Owners` name? is there any specific count of prefix/suffix is added to the string before and after respectively

Comment: Since you have no prior information of how many prefixes or suffixes you have in your file name, but have a fixed format, regex might not be the way to go. Alternatively, split the filename on `-` and get the array of strings by calling `ToArray()`. You can then call the `Contains` method on it. `a.Split('-').ToArray().Select(x => x.Trim().ToLower()).Contains(owner.Trim().ToLower());`  Here 'a' is your filename and 'owner'  is your owner name.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Owners are retrieved from a database using login/account info. And no, there is no specific count of prefix/suffix (though it probably won't be bigger than 1 or 2 each).

Comment: @SaiGummaluri I agree with you, splitting might be a good solution here. I really wish I could use regex in this case though (if possible). If regex is not possible, your way shall be the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're still looking for a regex solution then here is one

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public static bool FileBelongsToOwner(string filename, string owner)
{
            return Regex.Match(
                     filename, @"(?<=[^-]*-[^-]*-\s)[^-]+?(?=\s-[^-]+\.)").Value 
                         ==owner.Replace("/", "_");
}
```

---

the code first extracts the owner of the file and checks if it's the same as the passed owner.

#### Explanation of the regex

- `(?<=[^-]*-[^-]*-\s)` lookbehind : assert if there exists two `-` before this position ie the first part `Workflow - Personalized -`
- `[^-]+?` matches the minimum possible of characters that's not a minus sign `-`. (`+?` non greedy so it stops before the last space)
- `(?=\s-[^-]+\.)` lookahead : assert if there exists one minus sign followed by a period.

check it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzw5aF)

### Note

If you're sure that all the filenames that you have follow the rule that you gave then you could change the regex to something simpler ie `(?<=\s)[^-]+?(?=\s-[^-]+\..{4}$)`.
Check it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ySZ5Xn)

the lookbehind is to remove the space before the name. the lookahead is to assert that the extension is on minus sign away.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then parameters of `FileBelongsToOwner()` functions are described as,

- **`string filename`** : Name of file with it's owner name surrounded by prefix(es) and suffix(es).
- **`owner`** : Name of owner which you are getting from database.

Now you want to figure out given file is belongs to respective owner or not.

---

You can use [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) with [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1) to find out correct owner of the file

```
public static bool FileBelongsToOwner(string filename, string owner)
{
      owner = owner.Replace("/", "_");
      return filename.Split('-')       //Split by -
               .Select(x => !x.Trim().ToLower())  //Trim spaces and convert each word to its lower case
               .Contains(owner.ToLower());  //Return true if array contains owner name.
}
```